# Validar CPF na classe RegisterController do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Baixei o pacote https://github.com/LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator para realizar a validação de cpf no meu sistema. Segui as instruções da documentação, colocando o ValidatorProvider no app.php.

No meu sistema de cadastro, gostaria que só fossem salvos CPFs válidos. No entanto, não entendi como proceder com essa validação no RegisterController. Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'cpf' => 'formato_cpf',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Mas não funcionou. Por mais que eu coloque um cpf inválido ainda assim consigo realizar o cadastro no sistema. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: formato_cpf é para o formato, e cpf é a validação que confere os números ... você não está confundindo.?

Comment: Quando eu fiz a pergunta eu já tava meio desesperado porque eu usava 'cpf' e não funcionava, aí eu havia tentando o 'formato_cpf', obviamente sem êxito também. No entanto, hoje eu testei com 'cpf' e finalmente a validação funcionou. Não entendo o que aconteceu da primeira vez, talvez fosse necessário reiniciar o servidor ou o composer não havia mapeado o namespace do Laravel Legends. Nunca vou saber, mas agora está tudo funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando eu fiz a pergunta eu já tava meio desesperado porque eu usava 'cpf' e não funcionava, aí eu havia tentando o 'formato_cpf', obviamente sem êxito também. No entanto, hoje eu testei com 'cpf' e finalmente a validação funcionou. Não entendo o que aconteceu da primeira vez, talvez fosse necessário reiniciar o servidor ou o composer não havia mapeado o namespace do Laravel Legends. Nunca vou saber, mas agora está tudo funcionando.